# Mac OS X Lion - anyone get push notifications working with Urban Airship? Or otherwise?

Tags: macos, cocoa, push-notification, osx-lion

I have them working perfection on my iOS app. My MacOS app registers for the notifications OK, but I can't get the server I'm using (Urban Airship) to accept the .p12 I generated for my MacOS app. (It's not the same one I used for iOS, as the bundle IDs are completely different, of course.) The error message is that the certificate was rejected by Apple.

The iOS and MacOS apps are two different apps in Urban Airship.

Before I spend most of tomorrow horsing around with certificates, provisioning, etc., I'd like to know whether anyone has gotten this to work. I don't think my problem is in my code. Rather, it is in generating the credentials needed for Urban Airship.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can confirm that this works, and I only spent 2 hours horsing around. Turns out I uploaded to Urban Airship a .p12 file generated from the development certificate, not the push certificate. When I did that right, Urban Airship was happy, and the push indeed showed up on my Mac as a badge.

The certificate/provisioning profile/.p12 stuff is a mess, of course, but if you get it right it seems to work.

Comment: When using a p12 certificate different than the push devel/production certificate you will have a authentication or decryption failure.